# TextInputLayout error color not getting cleared?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textinputlayout

I have a TextInputLayout with an EditText inside it.

This is my xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Text" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

My java code:

```
((TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout)).setError("ERROR");
```

When I call **setError("ERROR")**, the and the label(hint) color and EditText's bottom line color gets changed to red and the error appears. This is the behaviour that I expect.

Now let's say I do not call **setError(null)** before destroying my activity. Now I open the same activity again. I can see that the bottom line remains red for all EditText fields inside in my application, although the label colour seems to be reset and the error message is dismissed. This is not always reproducible, but if I keep trying, I can eventually get it.

I am using a Nexus 4 with 5.1.1.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It should recreate the layout and I don't understand why are you getting red line even after destroying the activity. Can you post a little more code?

Comment: Hey man have u solved this . Mine also the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to a **bug in the AppCompat library**.

- [Issue 190829:   TextInputLayout setError causes all TILs in the app to have red underline](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190829)

> Reported by elyess.a...@gmail.com, Oct 19, 2015 Using design support
>   library 23.1.0
>
> Steps to reproduce the problem (including sample code if appropriate).
>
> - SetError on one TIL (i.e. in a form)
> - The TIL has a red underline (ok)
> - Navigate back and enter the activity again. Or go to another Activity with TILs.
>
> What happened.
>
> - All the TILs have a red underline, even in other Activities. (but no error text).
> - The red underlines disappear only after force closing the app.

Also reported here:

- [Issue 190355:  TextInputLayout setError() will not show an error after it is cleared](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190355)

---

Issue status was changed to `FutureRelease` on 11 Nov 2015, so we can hope for a fix coming soon.

In the meantime, it seems there are 3 workarounds:

- [compile with v23.0.1 of the library](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190355#c8)

  - but that introduces a similar issue where the error line does not reset
- [add an invisible `EditText` to the top of your layout](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190829#c9)
- [run the following code on your first `EditText`](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190829#c9)

  - `editText.setBackground(editText.getBackground().getConstantState().newDrawable())`

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved on version 23.1.1 of the com.android.support: ... libraries

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem what worked for me was changing my theme to extend from `Theme.Design.*`.
Source: [Issue 202051:  UnsupportedOperationException in TextInputLayout's counter](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202051)

Answer (score 0):

As @Richard said, it is a bug.
[Issue 190829: TextInputLayout setError causes all TILs in the app to have red underline](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190829)

I have used the solution of setting the constant state back to background. You can just extend the TextInputLayout with your own custom class where you override the setError() method:

```
public class CustomTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {

    // Constructors...

    @Override
    public void setError(@Nullable CharSequence error) {

        super.setError(error);
        if ((getEditText() != null && getEditText().getBackground() != null) &&
            (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 22 || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 21)) {
            Drawable drawable = getEditText().getBackground().getConstantState().newDrawable();
            getEditText().setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
        }
    }
}
```

And then I am reusing this class for wrapping EditTexts. I didn't experience any side effects.